# cakephp .htaccess with multiple domains

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, cross-domain

I have my cakephp .htaccess files set up as in the [cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/view/37/Apache-and-mod_rewrite-and-htaccess) and everything is working fine.

My web site currently has multiple domains, all of which point to the same site (e.g. www.site.com, www.site.co.uk). I'd like to set up a rule so that requests to www.site.co.uk/page are [permanently redirected](https://ukwebsolutionsdirect.co.uk/support/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=206) to www.site.com/page, etc.

I'm having trouble getting both rules to work together. Can anyone help me out?

---

EDITED TO INCLUDE FURTHER DETAILS:

Here is the .htaccess file in my web root:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine on

    # Force domain to be www.site.com
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.site\.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [R=permanent,NC]

    # For CakePHP   
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site\.com$   
    RewriteRule    ^(.*)$ app/webroot/$1    [NC]
</IfModule>
```

I also have a separate CakePHP app in a subdirectory: tbgroup. Here is the .htaccess file (tbgroup/.htaccess):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on

   # For CakePHP
   RewriteRule    ^(.*)$ app/webroot/$1    [NC]
</IfModule>
```

Everything works as fine: www.site.co.uk is redirected to www.site.com, www.site.co.uk/page is redirected to www.site.com/page. CakePHP works fine. The only problem is www.site.co.uk/tbgroup is not redirected to www.site.com/tbgroup - it remains as www.site.co.uk/tbgroup (and CakePHP works fine).

Try it out on the live site if you like (www.site.com or www.site.co.uk).

Comment: I've included the .htaccess files and given further details of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you've pointed out the answer in the permanent redirection link in your question.

It's really not related to cakephp. It's just mod-rewrite issue. You have yo put this code in your .htaccess file (under /app/webroot)

```
rewritecond %{http_host} ^(www.)?site.co.uk [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://site.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Comment: Thanks. This solves the problem (I've omitted the (www.)? as I prefer to keep the www). However, I now have a problem with a separate CakePHP app in a subdirectory that I didn't mention. I have modified my post to include the details.

Comment: I think the problem is because tbgroup is a real directory and the .htaccess in the parent directory is not used. Tro to move  # Force domain to be www.atdbio.com part in the tbgroup/.htaccess